# How do i write a method that will loop through an enum an inputted number of times?

Tags: java, loops, methods, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH, WEST, SOUTH, EAST;
}
```

and this method:

```
public void turn(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        //Change compass direction n times
    }
}
```

And what I need to do is change the direction by 90 degrees counter clockwise an inputted "n" number of times. I set up the enum so that it would be in the correct order, I just am not sure how I could make it so the current value compassDirection can be changed in terms of iterating through the enum "n" times.

Comment: Have a look at what `Direction.values()` returns... and I'd consider adding methods to the enum itself to return "this enum value turned 90 degrees clockwise" or "this enum value turned 90 degrees anti-clockwise". The naming is tricky, but you definitely want to make sure it doesn't imply that the call would change the existing value at all. For an implementation, you could use `ordinal()` to work out which value "this" is, then the array returned by `values()` to find the neighbour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate over the `enum` members.

In order to do so, every `enum` has a `.values()` method which returns an array with all valid values in the defined order.

So with

```
public void turn(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
            // Do something with direction
        }
    }
}
```

you basically achieve what you want.

---

Edit: After your clarification, I think you are rather after

```
public void turn(int n){
    Direction[] directions = Direction.values()
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int direction_index = i % directions.length;
        Direction direction = directions[direction_index];
        // Do something with direction
    }
}
```

or

```
public void turn(int n){
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
            if (i==n) return;
            i++
            // Do something with direction
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully described my question in the best way. What I mean is for example say I call turn(3), this would mean I want the value of my variable compassDirection to change 3 times. I.E, If i were north (0), I would want to loop through turn() 3 times, making it west (1), then the second time south (2), and the third time east (3). How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need an iteration here.
You can achieve turning like this:

```
public Direction turn(Direction initial, int turns)
{
    Direction[] dirs = Direction.values();
    return dirs[(initial.ordinal()+turns) % dirs.length];
}
```

In this code you are getting current element's index in enum, and based on number of turns you get the index of the result. And by the result index you can gen an enum value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    turn(6);
}

public static Direction turn(int n){
    Direction result = null;
    Direction[] values = Direction.values();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        result = values[i % values.length];
        System.out.println(i + " " + result);
    }
    return result;
}
```